# How to draw a picture like this?

Tags: drawing

[image]

***That is what l want,but l can only use Show,Plot3D to get something just like this***

[image]

What should l do?Thanks~

Comment: First of all you should post a Mathematica code for those who might wish to help you without wasting their time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Show[{
  Plot3D[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, x^2 + 0.15}, {x, -2, 1.9}, 
    PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[0.07]] /. Line -> Arrow

    }]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!